# Kruskal.test in R

Tags: r, p-value, kruskal-wallis

I'm using `kruskal.test` in R. The problem I'm having is that I wanted to find p-values for each categorical variable (ie. gender, separated by female and male).
If I have data:

```
Type month ethnicity length age sex
A    1     White     20     35  F
B    3     White     35     45  F
A    2     Hispanic  40     50  M
B    2     Hispanic  43     33  M
```

Something like this, and if I want to calculate p-values for the each ethnicity type by Type, what should I do?

Right now the code is:

```
kruskal.test(length~ Type, data=df)
```

but I can't do

```
kruskal.test(sex$M~ Type, data=df)
```

The data is not normally distributed. I appreciate any suggestions

Comment: You must provide two groups to `kruskal.test`, could you try to be more specific what you are trying to test. Do you mean to do `sex=="M"` instead of `sex$M`?

Comment: Yes, in the end, i want to show the p value for the mean of males in type a and b. like testing if the mean of males are different between A and B

Comment: The mean of what?

Comment: Maybe `kruskal.test(length ~ Type, data = subset(df, sex == "M"))`.

Comment: Note that the outcome should be numeric for `kruskal.test()` to make sense. Also, note that it is not testing means but shifts in the distribution conditional on the shape being the same in all groups.